# Can not access PHP-FPM site

Tags: linux, opensuse, php, fastcgi, fpm

Using OpenSUSE v15.2, Apache.

Installed PHP-FPM with zypper.
Followed instructions on this site:
https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Apache_FastCGI_and_PHP-FPM_configuration

I restarted Apache and PHP-FPM.
However the site is not loading in the browser.

**I get HTTP ERROR 502.**

`lynx http://10.20.30.40/info.php` results `Alert!: HTTP/1.0 502 cannotconnect`

Also get this error:

```
McAfee Web Gateway - Notification

Cannot Connect
   The proxy could not connect to the destination in time.
   URL:
     _____________________________________________________________________________________________________

   generated 2020-08-02 15:00:37 by McAfee Web Gateway
   Lynx/2.8.9dev.16 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1d
```

**Might be just a firewall issue?**

**Or error is in my Apache/PHP-FPM config?**

/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost 10.20.30.40:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName devsite.com

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mydir

    # RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteRule    ^(.*)$    https://devsite.com$1 [L,R=301]

    # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/srv/www/mydir$1


    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>


    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/mydir/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myhost.err
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myhost.acs combined

  LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to debug the problem with lynx browser locally and got this result:

```
lynx 127.0.0.1:9000

Looking up 127.0.0.1 first
Looking up 127.0.0.1:9000
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1:9000
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
Retrying as HTTP0 request.
Looking up 127.0.0.1:9000
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1:9000
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
Alert!: Unexpected network read error; connection aborted.
Can't Access `http://127.0.0.1:9000/'
Alert!: Unable to access document.

lynx: Can't access startfile
```

Also tried

```
lynx http://127.0.0.1/info.php


Looking up 127.0.0.1 first
Looking up 127.0.0.1
Making HTTP connection to 127.0.0.1
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

which executes phpinfo().
The php was not executed, just offered the info.php to download.
So php is not interpreted.

PHP-FPM log:

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm.log
[02-Aug-2020 01:37:29] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[02-Aug-2020 01:37:29] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[02-Aug-2020 01:37:29] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8099
[02-Aug-2020 01:37:29] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[02-Aug-2020 01:37:29] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[02-Aug-2020 01:39:47] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[02-Aug-2020 01:39:47] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[02-Aug-2020 01:39:47] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8202
[02-Aug-2020 01:39:47] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[02-Aug-2020 01:39:47] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Shows that it is running, and shows restarts, nothing more.

Apache error log:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
[Sun Aug 02 01:37:34.743959 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6160] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
AH00557: httpd-prefork: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for myhost
AH00558: httpd-prefork: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Aug 02 01:37:34.818193 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8113] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 02 01:37:34.818251 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8113] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -D SYSCONFIG -D SSL -C PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//loadmodule.conf -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//global.conf -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -c Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//include.conf -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Aug 02 01:39:45.771523 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8113] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
AH00557: httpd-prefork: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for myhost
AH00558: httpd-prefork: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Aug 02 01:39:45.852536 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8186] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Linux/SUSE) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 02 01:39:45.852586 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8186] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -D SYSCONFIG -D SSL -C PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//loadmodule.conf -C Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//global.conf -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -c Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d//include.conf -D SYSTEMD -D FOREGROUND'
```

In www.conf I enabled

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

But no /var/log/fpm-php.www.log was created.

Apache info:

```
apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
10.20.30.40:80           mysite.com (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/myhost.conf:1)
*:443                  mysite.com (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/myhost.ssl.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/srv/www"
Main DocumentRoot: "/srv/www/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: SYSCONFIG
Define: SSL
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="wwwrun" id=471
Group: name="www" id=471
```

/etc/apache2/conf.d/mod_fcgid.conf:

```
<IfModule fcgid_module>
FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/shm
# <FilesMatch "\.php$">
   # SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost/"
    # SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
# </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/php7/fpm/php-fpm.conf

```
[global]
include=/etc/php7/fpm/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

/etc/php7/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
[www]
user = wwwrun
group = www
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = wwwrun
listen.group = www
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Any idea, what can be the problem?

Comment: You's connecting to the same port with both `lynx` (a web browser) as you're telling apache to connect to PHP on. FastCGI is its own communication protocol outside of HTTP so if you're going to use `lynx` you need to connect to whatever port apache is listening on and look at the log files to determine why it might be failing (if it even is).

Comment: I modified the OP. Does it add any useful info?

Comment: Updated the OP with more config info.

Comment: You seem to be defining the PHP handler twice - once on its default port and once on port 9000

Comment: When you are connecting `lynx http://127.0.0.1/info.php`, you are probably not connecting to the `<VirtualHost 10.20.30.40:80>` that has the PHP handler definition. Would `lynx http://10.20.30.40/info.php` work any better?

Comment: `lynx http://10.20.30.40/info.php` results `Alert!: HTTP/1.0 502 cannotconnect`

Comment: Disabled handler in mod_fcgid.conf. Same result.